# Binding aspect to the super method call instead of the call on child

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, aop, spring-aop

I'm writing aspect and I want to add some logic after repository save method is executed. To achieve that I wrote:

```
@After("execution(* com.myApp.jpa.MyRepository.save(MyEntity)) && args(entity)")
```

Unfortunately, since my repository extends:
`org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository`

The aspect is bound to:

```
org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository#save
```

which works with *Iterable entities* instead of single object that can be accessed thought the super method:

```
org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository#save(S)
```

The question is: does syntax provide the way to write the expression that match only super method call for this case? 
I tried this:

```
@After("execution(* com.myApp.jpa.MyRepository.save(..)) && args(entity)")
```

However, it works for both methods, not only super call.